# Transforming Navigation Bar, translations and Media queries in CSS & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, mpmediaquery

I'm building a Website in HTML, CSS, and JS. I used this template for getting started: https://html5up.net/landed

Now when resizing the Window the Navbar at the top gets transformed to a dropdown Menu (or Burger Menu).

I'm trying to solve a problem where I can insert the Text from my translation file to the listItems within the transformed Navigation. I am very confused how this transformation happens and how i can for example make it happen on another MediaQuery as well.

```
"en": {
    "home": "Home",
    // other translations...
},
"de": {
    "home": "Startseite",
    // other translations...
}
```

I use this to set and toggle my translations which works great:

```
let translations;

// Function to toggle language
const toggleLanguage = (language) => {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-translate]');
    elements.forEach((element) => {
        const key = element.getAttribute('data-translate');
        element.innerHTML = translations[language][key] || translations['en'][key];
    });
};

// Function to load translations from the JSON file
const loadTranslations = () => {
    fetch('assets/js/translations.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            translations = data;
            const savedLanguage = localStorage.getItem('selectedLanguage') || 'de';
            document.documentElement.lang = savedLanguage;
            toggleLanguage(savedLanguage);

            // Add 'active' class to the saved language link
            const savedLangLink = document.querySelector(`[data-lang="${savedLanguage}"]`);
            if (savedLangLink) {
                savedLangLink.classList.add('active');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error loading translations:', error));
};

// Event listener for language toggle links
document.querySelectorAll('.lang-toggle').forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const newLanguage = event.target.getAttribute('data-lang');
        document.documentElement.lang = newLanguage;
        toggleLanguage(newLanguage);

        // Remove 'active' class from all links
        document.querySelectorAll('.lang-toggle').forEach((link) => {
            link.classList.remove('active');
        });

        // Add 'active' class to the clicked link
        event.target.classList.add('active');

        // Save the selected language to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('selectedLanguage', newLanguage);
    });
});

// Load translations when the DOM is ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadTranslations);
```

Here's my Nav:

```
<header id="header">
    <h1 id="logo" style="font-size: 200%; font-family:logoFont;"><a href="index.html">JS</a></h1>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul style="font-weight: bold;">
            <li><a href="index.html" data-translate="home"></a></li>
            <li><a data-translate="aboutNav" href="#about" class="scrolly"></a></li>
            <li><a data-translate="services" href="#services" class="scrolly"></a></li>
            <li><a data-translate="skills" href="#skills" class="scrolly"></a></li>
            <li><a data-translate="career" href="#career" class="scrolly"></a></li>
            <li style="padding-left: 7em;"><a data-translate="de" href="#" class="lang-toggle" data-lang="de">DE</a></li>
            <li style="margin-left: -0.01em;"><a data-translate="en" href="#" class="lang-toggle" data-lang="en">EN</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Now, when I resize the window, this MediaQuery takes action:

```
/* Small */
#navPanel,
#titleBar {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    /* Basic */
    html,
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    /* ... (other CSS rules) ... */

    /* Nav */
    #page-wrapper {
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
        -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
        padding-top: 44px !important;
    }

    #titleBar {
        /* ... (titleBar styles) ... */
    }

    #navPanel {
        /* ... (navPanel styles) ... */
    }

    /* ... (other CSS rules) ... */
}
```

And the **`Nav`** element transforms into a dropdown:

**Main.js**

```
// Nav.
$(
    '<div id="titleBar">' +
    '<a href="#navPanel" class="toggle"></a>' +
    '<span class="title">' + $('#logo').html() + '</span>' +
    '</div>'
).appendTo($body);
```

**Util.js**

```
$.fn.navList = function (translationData, language) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $a = $this.find('a'),
    b = [];

    $a.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            indent = Math.max(0, $this.parents('li').length - 1),
            href = $this.attr('href'),
            target = $this.attr('target'),
            translationKey = $this.data('translate').toLowerCase(); // Get translation key from data-translate attribute
        console.log('Translation Key:', translationKey);
        console.log('Translation Data:', translationData);

        // Find translation for the key in the provided translation data
        var translatedText = translationData[language][translationKey] || translationKey;

        b.push(
            '<a ' +
                'class="link depth-' + indent + ' scrolly"' + // Add 'scrolly' class
                ( (typeof target !== 'undefined' && target != '') ? ' target="' + target + '"' : '') +
                ( (typeof href !== 'undefined' && href != '') ? ' href="' + href + '"' : '') +
                ' data-translate="' + translationKey + '">' + // Set data-translate attribute
                '<span class="indent-' + indent + '"></span>' +
                translatedText + // Use translated text
            '</a>'
        );
    });

    return b.join('');
};

var translationData = {
    "en": {
        "home": "Home",
        // other translations...
    },
    "de": {
        "home": "Startseite",
        // other translations...
    }
};

// Callback function to initialize navigation after translation data is loaded
function initNavigation() {
    $('#nav').html($('#nav').navList(translationData, 'en')); // Example usage
    // Other initialization code for your navigation...
}

// Simulate loading translation data asynchronously (replace this with your actual data loading mechanism)
setTimeout(function() {
    initNavigation();
}, 1000);
```

What I'm trying to solve is the **`<li>`** elements within the transformed Nav don't have any text because the **`data-translate`** doesn't get passed with the transformation. Also, when I try to transform the Navbar in a different MediaQuery, I can't get it to work. Is there anyone who can make sense out of this? If I should provide additional code, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you reproduce this in either stackoverflow or over https://codesandbox.io/ ? seeing the actual working code will help in debugging